# alpine.js nested for loop - x-show only on subitem

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, alpine.js

is there a possibility to bind x-show on only the selected item ?

i have a data array with [{firstname:'test', meetings:'[{'day':'17', 'month':'02'},{'day':'18', 'month':'02'}] ...... and so on }]

i want to show only the user, and when i click on the user i want to show the meetings. like on tabulator js (group-by) the problem is, that when i click on a user, all other meetings are also shown up because the global variable open has been changed.

MyCode:

```
  <div class="w-full">
   <template x-for="user in data">
    <div class="block">
     <div  class="bg-primary-300 rounded-lg border text-lg" >
      <div x-html="user.firstname" class="font-bold hover:bg-gray-400 cursor-pointer" @click="{open = !open}"> </div>
       <div x-show="open">
        <div class="block">
          <template x-for="meet in user.meetings">
            <div class="flex ml-32 gap-2 border-b border-gray-700">
              <div x-text="meet.day">

              </div>
              <div x-text="meet.month ">

              </div>
           </template>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>  
   </div>
 </template>
</div>
```

how can i solve this problem ?

Thanks for helping, cheers Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've got a user id. You'll want to save the user id that's been clicked and then toggle open if the opened id matches the current user being iterated's id.

You can do this with `@click="open = user.id"` and `x-show="open === user.id"`

```html
<div class="w-full">
   <template x-for="user in data">
    <div class="block">
     <div  class="bg-primary-300 rounded-lg border text-lg" >
      <div x-html="user.firstname" class="font-bold hover:bg-gray-400 cursor-pointer" @click="open = open === user.id ? null : user.id" </div>
       <div x-show="open === user.id">
        <div class="block">
          <template x-for="meet in user.meetings">
            <div class="flex ml-32 gap-2 border-b border-gray-700">
              <div x-text="meet.day">

              </div>
              <div x-text="meet.month ">

              </div>
           </template>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>  
   </div>
 </template>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Hugo!! you are a great guy! Your solution is not toggling but it opens the user meetings and closing it after i click on another user. But it is not closing after i click on the same user. Do you understand what i mean ?

Comment: `@click="open = open === user.id ? null : user.id"`